# NMI error is received in centos 6.0

Tags: interrupts

I have CentOS 6.0 installed with the kernel version 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64. I'm getting this error since today. Until this morning everything was ok. Please tell me how could I resolve it.

> system showing "NMI received for unknown reason 31 on cpu 0 . dazzed and confused trying to continue. do you have any strange power saving mode enabled?"